# Cant preview image from second input field

Tags: javascript, html, image, tags, preview

Html, two input fields

```
<input id="image" type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">

<input id="pic" type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

JavaScript

`

```
  function previewFile() {
 var preview = document.querySelector('img');
var file    = `document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];



 var reader  = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
 preview.src = reader.result;
 }, false);
if (file) {
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
}
```

Image uploaded from first input field is getting previewed but not the second one

Comment: Do you see the preview of second input inside the first image?

Comment: [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first `Element` within the document, so your `preview` and `file`variables will always hold first matched elements, try using `id` as selectors

Comment: @AliSheikhpour no, not able to preview the second image

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti so what changes do i need to make in my js function

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution would be like assigning `id`s to elements and passing it as parameter to your function:

```
<input id="image" type="file" onchange="previewFile('image')"><br>
<img id="inp-image" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">

<input id="pic" type="file" onchange="previewFile('pic')"><br>
<img id="inp-pic" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

and js

```
function previewFile(sel) {
    var preview = document.querySelector('#inp-' + sel); // use selector
    var file = document.querySelector('#'+sel).files[0]; // use selector
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the input object to the JS function to decide what element you are working with. For example I use `nextElementSibling` and `this` as reference to desired element.

```
<input id="image" type="file" onchange="previewFile(this)">
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">

<input id="pic" type="file" onchange="previewFile(this)">
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

JavaScript

```
function previewFile(obj) {
var preview = this.nextElementSibling;
var file= obj.files[0];


var reader  = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
  preview.src = reader.result;
 }, false);
if (file) {
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
}
```

You can also give ID to all elements and pass IDs to the function e.g:

```
<input id="file1" type="file" onchange="previewFile('file1','preview1')">
<br>
<img id="preview1" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

Comment: Thank you. You can vote up or accept answers if they are helpful.